# Узнать, сколько символов считано ReadConsole

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Вот у меня такая строчка:

```
invoke ReadConsole, hInput, addr InputBuffer, 2, ADDR nRead, NULL
```

По идее в nRead должно храниться количество реально считанных символов?
Если там один символ, мне нужно делать одно действие, иначе - другое
Пишу вот так:

```
     mov ebx, nRead
     cmp ebx, 1
     je lbl
```

Но не работает. Что не так и как быть?

Comment: Для форматирования кода используйте кнопку {}

1. Попробуйте в отладчике посмотреть, какое значение лежит в nRead после вызова ReadConsole.
2. Возможно нужно mov ebx, [nRead], но со 100% гарантией не могу утверждать.

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю в отладчике (пользуюсь OllyDbg). Может, через какой-нибудь другой посмотреть?
Но попробовал прямо в программе вывести значение nread, Он вроде бы выводит то значение, которое в предыдущем аргументе (2).

Answer (score 1):

Протестировал на своей старой программе. Оказалось, что при вводе через ReadConsole вводится еще два символа перевода строки (CR, LF). Поэтому при вводе 1 символа, должно ввестись 3 (но т.к. указанный размер буфера равен 2, то вводится только 2), поэтому нужно расширить буфер хотя бы до 4 символов и сравнивать nRead с 3.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!